# Handling output of invoke-sqlcmd in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a sql query that outputs its result as a bit. I am trying to capture this output in a variable in PowerShell, and then use it in an IF/ELSE to decide the next step to run. The sql query is saved to a file and called using invoke-sqlcmd. I can't run this as a stored procedure.

The code snippet below always returns the else result "Create Mydb", and the Write-Output always displays 'You specified 0'. The database I am testing on should be returning a 1, so I don't think the result of the sql query is being set. I'd prefer to execute a .sql file rather than using -Query.

```
[int]$result = invoke-sqlcmd -Server $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -InputFile $InputFile
Write-Output "You specified $result"
If ($result.result -eq 1) {
    write-host("Mydb database already exists")
}
else {
    write-host("Create Mydb")
}
```

Comment: if `$result` is coerced to `[int]`, how could it have a `.result` property? integers are value types

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo $val` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo($val)`.  It happens to work with a _single_ argument, but breaks with multiple ones, because if you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.